# symfony save submitted form to database

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Maybe I am missing something, but in symfony examples, in form submission action there's nothing which indicates form data is saved to database. ([link](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/01-Form-Creation)). How can I save everything to db?

Example from the link:

```
public function executeSubmit($request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post'));

  $params = array(
    'name'    => $request->getParameter('name'),
    'email'   => $request->getParameter('email'),
    'message' => $request->getParameter('message'),
  );

  $this->redirect('contact/thankyou?'.http_build_query($params));
}
```

Comment: You are right. The codes will not save the form data into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/04-Propel-Integration:

> In a Web project, most forms are used to create or modify model objects. These objects are usually serialized in a database thanks to an ORM. Symfony's form system offers an additional layer for interfacing with Propel, symfony's built-in ORM, making the implementation of forms based on these model objects easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form that's based on a model (eg Doctrine or Propel object), you'll need to do something like the following in your action:

```
$this->form = new MyForm();

$this->form->bind($params);

if ($this->form->isValid())
{
  $this->form->save();
}
```

These seem to be the crucial steps that you're missing.  As others have pointed out, the Symfony tutorials provide good examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

As well as VolkerK's link, the jobeet tutorial covers doctrine (or propel if you prefer that as your ORM) forms.

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10